# Angular 8 typescript file replacement error

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular8, ng-build

I'm replacing html files with **angular.js** configurations, but if I need to replace a typescript file from component, it shows errors. I'm using angular 8.

**angular.js**

```
"production": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", // GOOD
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    },
    {
      "replace": "src/theme.css", // GOOD
      "with": "src/theme.prod.css"
    },
    {
      "replace": "src/app/login/login.component.html", // GOOD
      "with": "src/app/login/login.component.prod.html"
    },
    {
      "replace": "src/app/login/login.component.ts", // ERROR
      "with": "src/app/login/login.component.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
```

**error**:

```
ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class LoginComponent in /src/app/login/login.component.prod.ts! Add LoginComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

I have this **component header** in "prod" and "normal" file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
```

Is there a way to replace typescript file from component?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the `login.module.ts` as well to the file replacement and provide the correct declaration of the prod login component. If that does not work, maybe you can check the environment in your login component and change the behavior directly in there.

Comment: somewhere in your modules under declarations you must have ```LoginComponent```. That file propably fails to import the component. Could be related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13964

Comment: I have that declaration in `app.module.ts`, the error appears when I add the replace file option.